# How to print the variable loaded and assigned from file

Tags: printf, octave

I am just learning machine learning using Octave. I want to load the data from the file and assign the data to one variable, then I just want to print the data to the console.The data in data.txt file is several-rows and two-columns matrix.

```
data = load('data.txt');
x = data(:, 1);
y = data(:, 2);
printf x;
printf y;
```

After executing the code, x and y will show up on the console, it is not what I expected, I just want to check the data loaded from the file, how to print this? Do I use wrong command?

Comment: Just type `x`, without `print` and without semicolon.

Comment: Thank you very much and I just wonder the function of semicolon, without semicolon, it is still working.

Comment: The semicolon prevents the data beeing shown in the console...

Comment: @MichaelO.: I used your short comment as a base for a full answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just type `data` in console and press *enter* . This will print the contents of the data variable with all its elements. Do NOT add a semicolon at end of line. This would suppress output.

The explicit way doing this is the command

```
display(data)
```